# Did Murli donate his eyes to Aakash?

Tags: ending, andhadhun

Spoilers ahead- I recently watched the movie *Andhadhun*.

The movie ends with director showing that Aakash can still see with his eyes.  It made me confused about how did he get his eyes back as Simmi had made him blind pre-interval.

I watched several videos explaining the ending  but there was no mention of Murli.

Given that Murli used to be Akash's ally before he gets shot in the neck and most probably be dead.

Though the other mentioned ending explanations were quite convincing.

So my question is, is there any possibility that Murli might have donated his eyes to Aakash?

Comment: Yes doctor said murli's organ are ready for transplant since he is dead. so in my opinion, he got eyes from murli.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. when I rewatched the movie I also noticed the doctor saying it. I think as the director has given an open ending to the film, this might be given as a clue just to make the audience more confused about the ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR; Its highly unlikely Murli donated his eyes.

Akash got his cornea probably from

**1. Simi**

**2. Someone else, not Murli.**

Remember the way we were shown the movie ending. Akash & Doctor were going by the car toward private jet. And the scene is over and we see Akash in London. What happened after they were driving is just a **story** Akash told to Sophie (Radhika Apte). Remember at last, Sophie tells Akash that he should have agreed to Doctor and should have transplanted Simi's [cornea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornea).

Pay full attention to what Akash said on this: **nothing**. He just turned away from her as if he were hiding something (may be **story** of that rabbit (actually [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)) that resides on his stick!)[image: Akash's stick].

After that scene, the significant scene turns out that Akash knocks a can out of his path. This clearly implies that he did agree to what the Doctor had to say about donating Simi's organs and get a share of money &

- *Probably* his cornea matched with Simi's and they transplanted to Akash's eyes, or
- He got enough money to get someone else's cornea, but not Murli's, for cornea transplant has to be done within 1-2 hours after death, so its unlikely that they got to same hospital where Murli was dead and get there that fast. They didn't even know where were Murli and Sakhu were.

Answer (score 1):

No, **Murli cannot donate Akash his eyes.**

There are several possibilities for proving that.

First of all, I am a that person thinks **Akash was never blind**. So there is no question of donation

Let's assume Askash was blind, **the time of Murli's death** makes it impossible for an eye donation. Akash and the doctor just receive a phone call on that. There is not enough time for an eye transplant. 
Also considering how hospitals work, there will be a list of patients who are waiting for an eye transplant. So Akash cannot get Murli's eyes by any chance.

Comment: Akash was blinded completely. Remember there was attempt to murder him by Manohar (Manav Vij). He could have resisted if he was able to see at little. Attempt to remove his kidney was made, he could have doubted if he could have seen that there are not a single more patient in this hospital. He could have seen Simmi is trying to cut the rope and misguiding him toward breaking out of the hospital.

Comment: he was blind for sure.