# How was Akash able to see at the end of Andhadhun?

Tags: plot-explanation, andhadhun

In the last scene of movie Andhadhun, Akash (Ayushmaan khurana) was seen hitting a trash can with his stick. 
It seems like he was not blind at that time. How is this possible?

It was not explained in the movie.

Comment: The movie kept it open ended, it is upto the viewer's interpretation. Maybe he still was blind, hitting the can was coincidental. We don't know that.

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94337/did-murli-donate-his-eyes-to-aakash

Comment: @Mistu4u : Hitting the can may be coincidental but the way this scene was shown doesn't appear as coincidental.

Comment: one possible explanation is in this article - https://www.thisisbarry.com/film/andhadhun-ending-explained-what-really-happened/

Answer (score 0):

It's an open ending finish. But the probable meaning is Akash was not actually blind during the whole time. He made up all this and got himself out of the case.

Comment: Later half in the movie was more on to take eyes from Simi. So one thing was sure that he was blind.